# How to overlap the UIButton and UIImage in a View?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uibutton

I want to overlap with `UIImageView` and `UIButton` like the following picture.

[image]

The `UIImageView` is behind the two `UIButton`.

If I put the `UIImageView` behind these two `Button` , how can I sure the `UIButton` will not barricaded by the `UIImageView` ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make sure your buttons are visible and events are caught you can use `bringSubviewToFront`.

```
UIImageView *myImageView = //..alloc, init;
UIButton *button1 = //..alloc, init; 
UIButton *button2 = //..alloc, init; 
[self.view addSubview:myImageView];
[self.view addSubview:button1];
[self.view addSubview:button2];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:button1];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:button2];
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to enable the user interaction `userInteractionEnabled` of `UIImageView`.

Default value of it is NO, and setting YES will paas down the event to `UIButton`.

So structure wise on self view you can add image view and on image view buttons can be added.